# Difference between two Implementation of even and odd in Prolog

Tags: prolog

i have two implementation of Prolog , the Function is to decide if the given number is odd or even

the first one works correctly

```
even1(0).
even1(X) :- X>0 ,X1 is X-1, odd1(X1).

odd1(1).
odd1(X) :- X>1 , X1 is X-1, even1(X1).
```

even1(2) returns true

but the second one doesnt work correctly

```
even2(0).
even2(X) :- X>0 , odd2(X-1).

odd2(1).
odd2(X) :- X>1 , even2(X-1).
```

even2(2) returns false
can anyone explain to me whats is the difference between the two of them ?

Comment: It is good to do this kind of thing to learn about recursion but in practice I would probably do something more like `even(X) :- 0 =:= X mod 2.` Just FYI :)

Comment: @Dan: Add `X >= 0` to make it equivalent.

Comment: didnt understand what do u mean @false

Comment: @Tun I think @false is making a bit of a joke... negative numbers can be even, but your predicates are only defined for positive numbers because you need a base case for the recursion somewhere. `X>=0` in my version would instill in the simpler definition the same limitation, simply for symmetry with the recursive version.

Comment: @Dan im just new to the declarative world , the functions are made only to try to understand the recursion in prolog.

Comment: Wait until he corrects some code you're really proud of... Anyway, yeah, I just think it's good to have a "lay of the land" a bit. Recursion is definitely central to getting things done in Prolog.

Comment: `even(-2)` fails in your version since you are defining `even/1` for natural numbers. But @Dan proposed another variant that succeeds for this case. So they are different, and thus `X >= 0` is needed. No joke intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prolog is a *relational* language, not a *functional* language. Thus, when you call `odd2(X-1)`, the predicate argument, `X-1`, is not *evaluated* as an expression but interpreted as a **compound term**:

```
?- functor(X-1, Name, Arity).
Name =  (-),
Arity = 2.
```

You can check what happens when Prolog proves a query by using your system trace functionality:

```
?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- even2(2).
   Call: (8) even2(2) ? creep
   Call: (9) 2>0 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 2>0 ? creep
   Call: (9) odd2(2-1) ? creep
   Call: (10) 2-1>0 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 2-1>0 ? creep
   Call: (10) even2(2-1-1) ? creep
   Call: (11) 2-1-1>0 ? creep
   Fail: (11) 2-1-1>0 ? creep
   Fail: (10) even2(2-1-1) ? creep
   Fail: (9) odd2(2-1) ? creep
   Fail: (8) even2(2) ? creep
false.
```

Note that the expression `2-1-1` evaluates to zero but, being a compound term, the call `even2(2-1-1)` doesn't unify with your base case for the predicate, `even2(0)`:

```
?- even2(2-1-1) = even2(0).
false.

?- 2-1-1 = 0.
false.
```

Therefore, Prolog tries the second clause and the call eventually fails the `X>0` check. Note that `>/2`, by being an arithmetic comparison predicate, it does evaluate its arguments prior to the actual comparison.

Comment: ah thanks , i didnt know that i can trace what happend in the excution time , its clear right now :)