# Why can't Prolog find the sum when I phrase it in reverse?

Tags: prolog

Suppose I wish to solve for the sum of a list in SWI-Prolog. The most obvious solution would be something of the form:

```
sum([],0).
sum([H|T],S) :- sum(T, SofT), S is SofT + H.
```

and it works exactly as expected.

Out of curiosity, however, I decided to rephrase the problem to say we need to find the sum such that the sum of the tail is the total sum minus the head. Should be the same thing mathematically, albeit probably a little less natural. I wrote it up as

```
sum2([],0).
sum2([H|T],S) :- sum2(T, S-H).
```

I then perform my queries with a really simple test case and get the result:

```
?- sum([1], S).
S = 1.

?- sum2([1], S).
false.
```

SWI-Prolog appeared to be unable to backtrack the solution to sum2, and I'm wondering why that is. I actually had a gut feeling things might go down that way, but I'm still not sure what's actually happening here. I ran a tracer but didn't find the output terribly enlightening. I'm a total newbie with Prolog, so I suspect the question may be dumb or hint at some horrible misconception on my part.

Any explanations would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155460/difference-between-two-implementation-of-even-and-odd-in-prolog/52155505#52155505

Comment: @PauloMoura Thanks for that, I think you are right that it's the same root problem. I think I misunderstood the unification process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](http://www.dai.ed.ac.uk/groups/ssp/bookpages/quickprolog/node12.html)
Given two terms **T1** and **T2** and which are to be unified:

- If **T1** and **T2** are constants (i.e. atoms or numbers) then if they are the same succeed. Otherwise fail.
- If **T1** is a variable then instantiate **T1** to **T2**.
- Otherwise, If **T2** is a variable then instantiate **T2** to **T1**.
- Otherwise, if **T1** and **T2** are complex terms with the same arity (number of arguments), find the principal functor **F1** of **T1** and principal functor **F2** of **T2**. If these are the same, then take the ordered set of arguments of  of **T1** and the ordered set of arguments  of **T2**. For each pair of arguments **Am** and **Bm** from the same position in the term, **Am** must unify with **Bm**.
- Otherwise fail.

so when you run

```
?- sum2([1], S).
```

it has run

```
sum2([],S-1)
```

that has unified with

```
sum2([],0)
```

and it is going to unify S-1 to 0, which 0 and 1 are constant, and S is a variable.
but S-1 is not constant nor variable, so it has failed.

Comment: Interesting. I expected it to test individual arguments of the complex term until it found a result. I think I need to read up more on Prolog's rules for instantiation and unification. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly right, but some of your variable names seem to have disappeared in the paste ("...the principal functor of . If these are...").